# How is a listener added for a specific keyword?

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I have a parser grammar and lexer grammar from which ANTLR4 4.7 generates a parser and lexer, no problem. The entry points in the listener logic are great but I'd like to listen for specific keywords in the language. **No idea where to start adding that.**

I am using the ANTLR4 plugin for Eclipse to generate the parser and lexer from the grammar.

Comment: Is that keyword you are listening for a single lexer token or should it be an arbitrary keyword?

Comment: @Raven Each keyword would a single lexer token and I want to pick which of them to listen for.

Comment: So you'd have the lexer rules A, B and C. You are then parsing the input and want to be able to set whether to listen for A, B Or C, right? Do you want to be notified during parsing or during parse tree walking? I think the former is the easier one to accomplish...

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the generated `xyzBaseListener` there are 4 non-specific methods that you can override to suit your need:

```
@Override public void enterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) { }
@Override public void exitEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx) { }
@Override public void visitTerminal(TerminalNode node) { }
@Override public void visitErrorNode(ErrorNode node) { }
```

e.g.

```
public class Tester extends xyzBaseListener
{
  // ... other useful stuff
  @Override public void visitTerminal(TerminalNode node) {
    System.out.println("Saw token '" + node.getText() + "'");
  }
}
```

The reference book has examples for how to subclass the base listener and wire up the listener.